# Actions=Output ignored

Tags: network-protocols, openflow, sdn

I'm seeing an issue adding flows manually on ovs version 2.3.1 when specifying actions=output port.  When the flow's action=normal, packets flow as expected, but as soon as I change the action to egress the desired output port, the flow is no longer matched.  It appears that there may be a bug when using output as an action, but it may be my mistake - has anyone else seen this?

Example of a manual flow that allows 192.168.2.1 on port 31 to ping 192.168.2.3 on port 33, and vice versa:

```
ovs-ofctl add-flow sdn-br1 nw_src=192.168.2.1,nw_dst=192.168.2.3,actions=normal

ovs-ofctl add-flow sdn-br1 nw_src=192.168.2.3,nw_dst=192.168.2.1,actions=normal
```

As soon as I change the action to output, there are no matches on the flow:

```
ovs-ofctl add-flow sdn-br1 nw_src=192.168.2.1,nw_dst=192.168.2.3,actions=output:33

ovs-ofctl add-flow sdn-br1 nw_src=192.168.2.3,nw_dst=192.168.2.1,actions=output:31
```

*arp is also allowed and working as expected.

Comment: Have you removed the 'output=normal' flows?

Comment: Correct.  I double-checked, deleted all flows and started from scratch.  Packets timeout unless I specifiy the action as normal.